# Max function - with join

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables

```
SalesAlias a
    Field 1: SalesAliasID
    Field 2: Code
    Field 3: SellAsDescr
    Field 4: ProdCOTGroupID

ProdCOTGroup c
    Field 1: ProdCOTGroupID
    Field 2: Code
    Field 3: LongDescr

SalesAliasHistory  g
    Field1: SalesAliasID
    Field2: EffDttm
    Field3: DefListPrice
```

I am trying to pull the DefListPrice for the max EffDttm by selecting a ProdCOTGroup.Code

This is not working:

```
SELECT a.SalesAliasID
    , a.Code
    , a.SellAsDescr
    , g.code
    , g.longdescr
    , b.EffDtTm
    , b.DefListPrice 
FROM dbo.SalesAlias a 
    , (
        SELECT MAX(EffDtTm) AS maxdate
            , b.SalesAliasID 
        FROM dbo.SalesAliasHistory b
        GROUP BY SalesAliasID
      ) maxresults
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SalesAliasHistory b ON a.SalesAliasID = b.SalesAliasID 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ProdCOTGroup g ON a.DEFProdCOTGroupID = g.ProdCOTGroupID
WHERE b.SalesAliasID = maxresults.SalesAliasID
    AND g.Code = '6720'
```

Pricing table

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: How is this code not working? No records? Incorrect records? Duplicate records? Reruns of Sanford and Sons?

Comment: from use of `dbo.` prefix on the tables, I'm assuming this is SQL Server.

Comment: `DEFProdCOTGroupID` does not exist in your table definitions.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually filtering by any form of maxDate. You need to include the maxdate in your JOIN filtering for maximum efficiency, like below:

```
SELECT a.SalesAliasID
    , a.Code
    , a.SellAsDescr
    , g.code
    , g.longdescr
    , b.EffDtTm
    , b.DefListPrice 
FROM dbo.SalesAlias a 
INNER JOIN dbo.SalesAliasHistory b 
    ON a.SalesAliasID = b.SalesAliasID 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(EffDtTm) AS maxdate
        , b.SalesAliasID 
    FROM dbo.SalesAliasHistory b
    GROUP BY SalesAliasID
    ) maxresults
    ON b.SalesAliasID = maxresults.SalesAliasID
    AND b.EffDtTm = maxresults.maxdate
INNER JOIN dbo.ProdCOTGroup g 
    ON a.DEFProdCOTGroupID = g.ProdCOTGroupID
WHERE b.SalesAliasID = maxresults.SalesAliasID
    AND g.Code = '6720'
```

Note that I also changed your JOINs to INNER JOINs. Since both joins have a mandatory value or comparison in the WHERE clause, this means the records must exist. If they must exist, an INNER JOIN simplifies the logic needed to obtain optimal query plan results. This small change can result in large overall improvements, depending on how the query analyzer has processed the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear in a number of ways; it would be useful to see sample data, actual table definitions, and expected results.

Having said that, perhaps this does what you want, or helps you get there:

```
SELECT a.SalesAliasID
    , a.Code
    , a.SellAsDescr
    , g.code
    , g.longdescr
    , b.EffDtTm
    , b.DefListPrice 
FROM dbo.SalesAlias a 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SalesAliasHistory b ON a.SalesAliasID = b.SalesAliasID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProdCOTGroup g ON a.ProdCOTGroupID = g.ProdCOTGroupID
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(EffDtTm) AS maxdate
            , b.SalesAliasID 
        FROM dbo.SalesAliasHistory b
        GROUP BY SalesAliasID
      ) maxresults ON a.SalesAliasID = maxresults.SalesAliasID 
                    AND b.EffDttm = maxresults.maxdate
WHERE b.SalesAliasID = maxresults.SalesAliasID
    AND g.Code = '6720';
```

The major change here is I'm joining the `maxresults` on *both* `SalesAliasID` *and* `maxdate = EffDttm`, to return only rows with the most recent `EffDttm`.  I also changed the joins to `INNER` joins.